# Localization with MVC4 Routes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to put differents languages in my website and I don't really understand the way to set correctly my routes to get it to work. Because with what I have currently i get a Redirection Loop.

So here's the code :

```
routes.MapRoute(
      null,
      url: "{culture}/{pageName}",
      defaults: new
      {
        culture = UrlParameter.Optional,
        controller = "Redirect",
        action = "Index",
        pageName = "debug"
      });
        routes.MapRoute(
  null,
  "{pageName}/",
  new { controller = "Landing", action = "Index" }
  );
  routes.MapRoute(
  null,
  "{culture}/{pageName}/",
  new { controller = "Landing", action = "Index" },
  new { culture = "^[a-z]{2}" }
  );
  routes.MapRoute(
  null,
  "{culture}/blog/{pageName}",
  new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" },
  new { culture = "^[a-z]{2}" }
  );
  routes.MapRoute(
  null,
  "blog/{pageName}",
  new { controller = "Blog", action = "Index" }
  );
```

**The question is : How to correctly set my routes to see the site that way :**

If hitting `/pageName` > Go to `/pageName` (the defaultCulture is set after and set to english)
else If `/en/pageName` > Redirect to `/pageName`
else If `/AnyCulture/pageName` > go to `/AnyCulture/pageName`
else `/incorrectUrl` > Go to home

Thanks for reading / answering :)

Answer (score 0):

You must set the parameter for the culture,  so that the culture is recognized as a parameter and the according action/controller can handle it like implying your controller/action has such a parameter:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
      null,
      "{culture}/{pageName}/",
      new { controller = "Landing", action = "Index", culture = UrlParameter.Optional },
      new { culture = "^[a-z]{2}" }
      );
```